# Powershell Script to could notepad time

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a quick script using dot notations that opens notepad, runs the script for a few seconds then closes notepad and the script tells how long it was open in seconds. I can't see what I'm doing wrong as it is following the steps.

```
$Notepad = Get-Process -Name notepad
$Notepad.WaitForExit()
$Time = New-TimeSpan $notepad.StartTime
$Seconds = $Time.Seconds

Write-Host "Notepad ran for $Seconds seconds"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ah its the ordering line 2 and 3 needed to be swapped. Im being lead by the blind as far as there teachin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course there are more ways to attack this, yet what you are doing won't work, because you are calling a time check after you started and closed notepad.
Also, there is nothing in the time variable when you do.

This will do what you are after...

```
Clear-Host
Start-Process -FilePath notepad.exe 
$Notepad = Get-Process -Name notepad
$StartTime = Get-Date
$Notepad.WaitForExit()
$EndTime = Get-Date
$ElapsedTime = (New-TimeSpan -Start $StartTime -End $EndTime).Seconds
"Notepad ran for $ElapsedTime seconds"

Notepad ran for 4 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its most exactly if you use the properties of the process object

```
$proc = Start-Process notepad -PassThru -Wait
"Notepad ran for $(($proc.ExitTime - $proc.StartTime).Seconds)"
```